# How to install multiple perl modules at once using CPAN

Tags: perl, cpan

Is it possible to install multiple modules using CPAN? I've tried:

```
perl -MCPAN -e 'install DBIx::Transaction File::Basename::Object'
```

but I get this error:

```
Can't locate object method "Transaction" via package "DBIx" at -e line 1
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```bash
cpan DBIx::Transaction File::Basename::Object
```

Use the `cpan` that was installed by the `perl` for which you want to install.

---

If you have problems installing for the correct `perl`, explicitly use the correct `perl`.

```bash
.../perl -S cpan DBIx::Transaction File::Basename::Object
```

or

```bash
.../perl -MCPAN -e'install($_) for @ARGV' DBIx::Transaction File::Basename::Object
```

---

The problem you have is the unquoted use of `DBIx::Transaction`.

Answer (score 11):

You need a separate `install` command for each module:

```
perl -MCPAN -e 'install DBIx::Transaction; install File::Basename::Object'
```

If you want to simplify the install process even more, take a look at [`cpanm`](https://metacpan.org/pod/cpanm), which requires no configuration and by default will install modules without prompting.

You can install both modules with a single `cpanm` command like this:

```
cpanm DBIx::Transaction File::Basename::Object
```

Although as ikegami points out, this is not exactly the same as the first command since you can't specify which version of `perl` to use.

Comment: That last command is equivalent to `cpan DBIx::Transaction File::Basename::Object` (use a `cpan` and the `perl` it was installed with), not `perl -MCPAN -e 'install DBIx::Transaction; install File::Basename::Object'` (use the specified `perl`). // Not sure how installing a whole new installer is easier than pressnig Enter the first time `cpan` is used.

Comment: @ikegami Thanks, fixed the "equivalent" part. I prefer `cpanm` over `cpan` since it is 1) less verbose, 2) doesn't prompt by default, and 3) seems to Just Work more often than `cpan`. I know you can configure `cpan` to not prompt and such, but I'd rather install `cpanm` with a single command and never have to worry about configuration again.

Comment: @ikegami Having said that, I can see how my "If you want to simplify the install process even more" bit is an over-generalization. It may not be simpler for someone managing a large number of systems, for example.

Comment: It doesn't simplify the process at all. One command to install vs one command to set the `prerequisites_policy`. In context, it actually complicates the process by getting someone to convert from a known and used system. // As for working, I've never had a single problem with `cpan` across 3 OSs and 8 version of Perl. // As for verbosity, 99% of the output comes from the installers, not `cpan`.

Comment: @ikegami `cpan DBI` produced 794 lines of output compared to only 6 for `cpanm DBI`. The first time I tried installing a module with `cpan`, I was prompted to answer about a long series of questions about configuration, many of which were utterly meaningless to me as someone new to Perl. I had to do that on every system I wanted to install a module on, which was annoying enough that I just installed `cpanm` and never bothered with `cpan` again. I think `cpanm` is more beginner friendly than `cpan`, hence my recommendation.

Comment: Re "I was prompted to answer about a long series of questions", The only question is something to the effect of "Do you want cpan to configure itsef? [y]"

Comment: Before using the comand "perl -MCPAN -e 'install DBIx::Transaction; install File::Basename::Object'" run "which perl" command to find the exact path of your perl  then use that path instead of perl . In my case I used "/usr/bin/perl -MCPAN -e 'install IO::Stringy; install IO::Tty; install IPC::Cmd; install JSON::PP; install Lingua::PT::Stemmer; install Lingua::Stem; install Lingua::Stem::Fr; install Lingua::Stem::It'"